# Retrieve TextView clicked row number

Tags: android, textview, row, clickable

Really stupid question here, but could not find an answer googling.

I have a clickable textview.
How to retrieve the row's number that is clicked??

Comment: `TextView`s do not have a "row number". Are you working in a `ListView`? What's your implementation?

Comment: Not really. Just a textview where I write lines with '\n' at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't that stupid because there is no built-in method, that I know of, to do this.

However you can use:

- [`getLineHeight()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineHeight%28%29) to determine how tall each line is in the TextView and
- [`MotionEvent#getY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY%28int%29) in an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to calculate which line was clicked.

---

Basic example:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            float line = FloatMath.floor(event.getY() / textView.getLineHeight());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

From the `getLineHeight()` documentation:

> Note that markup within the text can cause individual lines to be taller or shorter than this height, and the layout may contain additional first- or last-line padding.

So if you have modified any attribute listed above, you'll need to account for that as well.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Still, getHeight() does not give me the number of lines, getScrollY() gives me 0 even when it is scrolled, I get "getY() is undefined for this type of view" and same for getLineHeight().

Comment: Ha, I was just updating my answer to make that more clear and remove any unnecessary step.

Comment: I posted a quick example. I hope it helps get you started.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot, Sam!! A simple (int)(MotionEvent.getY()/View.getHeight()) retrieves the line number. getScrollY() does not seem to be needed (always 0). This works with OnTouch, though: OnClick does not pass a MotionEvent...